# Azure Data Factory - Tell if current pipeline is already running

Tags: rest, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Calling the Rest API queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01 always returns an empty array, regardless of the filters used. This occurs on Published Triggers. I am aware that it doesn't work on DEBUG runs. The JSON body is correct, so what else could cause no data  to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

I created a pipeline added triggered to that

[image]

I call the  Rest API queryPipelineRun?api-version=2018-06-01 with required details.

[image]

[image]

I run it; I got empty array.

[image]

I added

```
lastUpdatedAfter: "2023-06-16T00:36:44.3345758Z",
lastUpdatedBefore: "2023-06-18T00:49:48.3686473Z"
```

to body.

[image]

Agin run the rest API. It run successfully, gave details of pipeline.

[image]